# MySQL - SELECT WHERE condition based on value of another SELECT

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have two MySQL Querys where I am trying to use count and results from first select in condition for the second select.

Here is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT m.name, m.id         
FROM members m                      
WHERE m.online_status = 1 {$dep} ORDER BY m.name ASC";


$sql_second = "SELECT time_management.clientid, clients.client,
SUM( CASE WHEN MONTH(`date`) = 1 AND taskid <> 1 AND YEAR(date)='$year' THEN TIME_TO_SEC( `time` ) AND user = (result from previouse slect) ELSE 0 END) AS (user_1)                     
FROM time_management
LEFT JOIN clients ON time_management.clientid = clients.id
WHERE {$dep_where} = {$department_var}
GROUP BY clientid";
```

So first select is selecting all users which are unknown value. Name and ID

In the second query what I need is to Select for example:

let's say the first query returns

```
id:1 name: Jon
id:2 name: Mike
id:3 name: Dave
```

**Total results: 3**

so in this case in the second query the following line have to be repeaded 3 times for each user:

```
SUM( CASE WHEN MONTH(`date`) = 1 AND taskid <> 1 AND YEAR(date)='$year' THEN TIME_TO_SEC( `time` ) AND user = (result from previouse slect) ELSE 0 END) AS (user_1)
```

where user will be = to 1,2,3 for each line and (user_1) willbe (user_2), (user_3)

Is there a way this operation to be realized directly inside MySQL ? if now how it should be solved ?

Comment: Probably. See JOINs. Or see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query